# Chrome javascript resize slowness?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, resize

The problem I am having is that, when I resize the browser window on my site http://reggi.com/so/chromeglitch chrome is very laggy. So much so that it seams to have a white background and a floating scrollbar.

Here is a image of resizing taking place right before it realigns:
[image: In process of resizing]
The problem I am having is with chrome specifically. Anyone know why this might be happening? I would appreciate it if anyone points me in the direction of any fixes or discussions on this issue. This does not happen in any other browser I have tested, all of them run really smoothly except chrome.

I am running:

- Mac OS X 10.6.5
- Chrome 11.0.696.68
- Safari Version 5.0.3 (6533.19.4)
- Firefox 4.0.1
- Opera 11.10

Comment: Although this might not be the problem, consider using thumbnails for the images, one of them is 2380×2912 (and make them clickable, because most people now won't notice the large versions). This would also improve page loading time for the first visit.

Comment: I was putting off sizing them down untill I convert it to a wordpress theme. I just sized them and it works much better thanks. This woulda drove me crazy. How did this not happen for Gary Green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer as it seems to have solved your problem at least partially.

Consider using thumbnails for the images, one of them is 2380×2912 (and make them clickable, because most people now won't notice the large versions). This would also improve page loading time for the first visit.

Note that the points Gary listed can still be the source of the issue:

- Extensions dealing with images could slow the process down
- GPU will have to do the scaling, driver issue could mean slow GPU<->CPU traffic
- CPU/memory usage will be increased with large images

If you want to track down the source of the problem further, you could do some debugging like deactivating all extensions, disabling hardware accelerating and monitoring CPU/memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

Seems fine to me in both Chrome 10.0.648 and Firefox 4.0.1.

- Are you sure it's not a Chrome Extension that's throwing the site around?
- As pages are hardware accelerated, it could be a driver issue.
- Check what your CPU/memory usage looks like